# How to use main function and while function together

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a loop that runs my function so long as the user keeps entering words. (i.e., stops when no word is entered.)

Everything except loop part is working. I do not know how to use while function with main function.

```
done = False
while not done:

    def main():
        words = str(input("Please enter a word: "))
        words = words.split()
        for word in range(len(words)):
            i = words[word]
            if i[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
                words[word] = i+'way'
            elif i[0] not in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
                words[word] = i[1:]+i[0]+'ay' 
            else:
                print('STOP')
                done = True
                break
            return ' '.join(words)

    def t(str):
            return str[0]+str[1]

    if __name__ == "__main__":
            x = main()
            print(x)
```

Comment: Writing a function in `while` loop. Bad practice.

Comment: Bring `while` inside `main()`.

Comment: What about putting the while inside the function rather than the other way around?

Comment: I can't keep entering a word if I bring while loop inside the main function.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of having a main function is to encapsulate **all of the code** in it and execute it only if the the file is not called as a module (`if __name__ == '__main__'`). Not very pythonic from my point of view but it would go something like this:

```
def t(str):
    # unused function btw
    return str[0]+str[1]

def main():
    done = False
    while not done:

        words = str(input("Please enter a word: "))
        words = words.split()
        for word in range(len(words)):
            i = words[word]
            if i[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
                words[word] = i+'way'
            elif i[0] not in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
                words[word] = i[1:]+i[0]+'ay' 
            else:
                # this doesn't make any sense
                # you're covering all possible scenarios
                # with the if and elif
                # this code will never be executed
                print('STOP')
                done = True
                break
        # note that this return has to be out of the for
        # otherwise it would only make one iteration
        # probably out of the while loop too
        return ' '.join(words)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        x = main()
        print(x)
```

Comment: Notice that since there is a break after `done` is set to `True`, then the flag is simply unecessary

Comment: This won't print anything until after `main` is done. You will want to refactor further, perhaps to put the input loop in `main` and the actual `pig_latin` logic in a function of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactoring which makes the following modifications.

- The `def` should be outside the `while` loop; redefining the same function again and again makes no sense.
- The read-eval-print loop is in `main` which calls `pig_latin` for the actual Pig Latin logic.

Some additional comments in-line.

```
def pig_latin(string):
    # Don't use the same variable name for a string and a list
    words = string.split()
    for word in range(len(words)):
        i = words[word]
        if i[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
            words[word] = i+'way'
        # no need for "elif", you already tested this
        else:
            words[word] = i[1:]+i[0]+'ay' 
    # Outdented -- don't return too early
    return ' '.join(words)

# Commented out -- this function is not used
"""
def t(str):
        return str[0]+str[1]
"""

def main():
    while True:
        # No need for str(); input always returns a string
        words = input("Please enter a word: ")
        if words == "":
            print('STOP')
            break
        print(pig_latin(words))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Put absolutely no real logic here; just dispatch
    main()
```

Notice how all the user interaction is isolated in one lump, and the actual function (sic) to translate the text is separate.